Gnome/Xrandr Disable monitors settings automation
How to disable gnome/xrandr from automatically mess with my monitors layout and settings?
Details:
Gnome makes a lot mess with xrandr to the monitors settings the moment it come back from screen idle... All monitors are missed up, the resolutions are changed/swapped between connected displays, the layout gets changed! This is considered a bug to be reported, but until such thing gets resolved, I need a quick way to just disable that behavior and manage my display settings, resolution and layout via nvidia-settings instead.
This automation probably works fine for single monitor, or two monitors connected with simple setup, however, in my case, I'm connecting three monitors, where each have different resolution/panning settings, with absolute layout offset on each. Obviously, gnome display settings cannot do such settings, it can only be done by nvidia-settings, fortunately gnome display settings will read it and write it to monitors.xml, but every time the monitors go to DPMS, and resumed, everything is messed up.
To be able to restore my settings on login, I had to set the correct monitors.xml file permissions to Read Only, this helped forces the daemon to not be able to change my file and work fine on login, but unfortunately that when resuming from screen idle, it doesn't read back the file but changes the display settings on the fly.
